# pandas DataFrame explode column contents

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
         0 1
0  [1,2,3] 1
1  [2,2,1] 1
2  [1,2,1] 1
...
```

The last column is the label and each of the arrays under column '0' are supposed to be different datapoints for a given class.

I want this to be turned into:

```
   x0 x1 x2 label
0  1  2  3  1
1  2  2  1  1
2  1  2  1  1
```

I have tried the following with no luck

```
ds = ds.apply(lambda x: numpy.ravel(x))
```

That was result of the following, obviously that is not the right way to do this.

```
<list>.extend(zip(points,labels))
ds = pandas.core.frame.DataFrame(data=<list>)
```

Any help is appreciated, on how to fix the actual dataset or create it correctly having the two lists (points and labels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. First remove your 1 column (so we dont mess the naming):

```
df['id'] = df[1]
df = df.drop(1, axis = 1)
```

Then create an objs, with what we want to concat, and concat:

```
objs = [df, pd.DataFrame(df[0].tolist())]
pd.concat(objs, axis=1)



           0    id  0   1   2
0   [1, 2, 3]   1   1   2   3
1   [2, 2, 1]   1   2   2   1
2   [1, 2, 1]   1   1   2   1
```

Comment: This solution works the best! I have modified a little the second part to: `pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(list(df[0]))], axis=1)`, seems to perform slightly better than when using `.tolist()`. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume your current column titles are text instead of integers.

```
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(zip(*df['0'])), df['1']], axis=1)
df2.columns = ['x' + str(c) for c in df2.columns[:-1]] + ['label']

>>> df2
   x0  x1  x2  label
0   1   2   1      1
1   2   2   2      1
2   3   1   1      1
```

`zip` used with the `*` operator unzips the list:

```
>>> zip(*df['0'])
[(1, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 1, 1)]
```

So you can easily expand your dataframe:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(zip(*df['0']))
   0  1  2
0  1  2  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  1  1
```

You then just need to concatenate the last column and rename all of the columns.

Comment: The columns are integers. When I tried pd.DataFrame(zip(*ds[0])) I get the following error: frame.py 283                 mgr = self._init_dict({}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    284         elif isinstance(data, collections.Iterator):
--> 285             raise TypeError("data argument can't be an iterator")
    286         else:
    287             try:

TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your dataframe differently to get what you want instead of trying to explode the column. See code below,

```
import pandas as pd
points = [[1,2,3],[2,2,1],[1,2,1]]
labels = [1,1,1]
x0 = [p[0] for p in points]
x1 = [p[1] for p in points]
x2 = [p[2] for p in points]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x0': x0,'x1': x1,'x2': x2, 'label': labels})
print (df)
```

To get,

```
   label  x0  x1  x2
0      1   1   2   3
1      1   2   2   1
2      1   1   2   1
```

Answer (score -1):

The best I can offer:

```
import numpy as np
# first convert your lists to an array, then iterate
tmp = np.array( df[0].tolist() )

for r in np.arange(0,3):
    df['x' + str(r)] = tmp[:,r]
```