# Splitting Pandas dataframe column full of strings by unique values Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a single series (column) of strings that are white space separated and concatenated together.

The dataframe column looks like:

```
[In]: df

[Out]:
 0   -- Generated 
 1   -- Formatting      
 2   -- Project1     
 3   -- Help        
 4   GRI                               -- Gen     
 5   S-P                               -- Gen
 6   COORD-SYS                         -- Gen
 7   COORD                             -- Gen
 8     318108.6945 6146696.895 1829.01714 318108.6945 6146696.895 
 9     1917.90444 334108.6945 6146696.895 1610.670059 334108.6945 
 10    6146696.895 1713.102355 350108.6945 6146696.895 1417.752346 350108.6945 
 11    NEF                             -- Gen
 12    318108.6945 6146696.895 1829.01714 318108.6945 6146696.895 
       2025.480832 326108.6945 6146696.895 1716.342492 326108.6945
 13    1917.90444 334108.6945 6146696.895 1610.670059 334108.6945 
       6146696.895 1813.845155 342108.6945 342108.6945
.
.
```

I'd like to separate this one column dataframe by the strings that **aren't numbers** and take all the numerical values underneath them until the next non-numeric value appears.

The output I need (for example for COORD and similar for NEF) would look like this:

```
[In]: df_COORD 

[Out]:


 0     COORD       1            2           3           4            5         
 1     318108.6945 6146696.895  1829.01714  318108.6945 6146696.895  nan
 2     1917.90444  334108.6945  6146696.895 1610.670059 334108.6945  nan
 3     6146696.895 1713.102355  350108.6945 6146696.895 1417.752346 350108.6945
```

I've first attempted at using something like:

```
df_COORD = pd.DataFrame(df[0][7:11]).reset_index(drop=True)
df_COORD= df_COORD.rename(columns=df_COORD.iloc[0]).drop(0)
df_COORD= df_COORD[file_coord.iloc[0][0]].str.split(expand=True)
```

Which works but I want to not have to explicitly state which rows I want; I'd like to separate based off the column value containing `COORD` or `NEF` or any other `list` of unique strings and grab data underneath until it reaches another lettered only string.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558954/pandas-dataframe-explode-column-contents)

Comment: This takes a list from a column and separates it but I'd like to grab all the data underneath each non-numerical column entry.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, what you need is to flag the block of related rows and then use groupby to create separate data frames. Based on your description, a new DF should start from a line containing non-numbers. Assume your origin DF has this column with the default name `0`:

```
# flag the block based on the regex and cumsum()
# Warning: you might also consider scientific notation of numbers in regex
g1 = (df[0].str.contains('[^\d.\s+-]')).cumsum()

# initialize the dict for all sub-dataframes
dfs = {}

for g, d in df.groupby(g1):
    # having only 1 row in the sub-dataframue, then they are unrelated and skipped
    if d[0].size == 1: continue

    # do whatever you want to groups with rows containing numbers
    d = d[0].str.strip(' \t').str.split(expand=True)
    dname = d[0].iat[0]
    dfs[dname] = d.iloc[1:,:].rename(columns={0:dname})
    print(dfs[dname])
```